# WFP http request a json

Tags: c#, json, windows-forms

Hola amigos quiero hacer un http request pero ahora en WFP y quisiera saber cómo puedo hacerlo, tengo una vista con un botón, me gustaría ejecutar un metodo que vaya por mis datos y me los muestre en una tabla, pero con cacharlos bien me doy por bien servido. Hasta ahora no tengo la tabla y solo tengo hasta aquí.

```
      private async  void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await ProcessRequest();

    }


    private async Task<string> ProcessRequest()
    {
        //incluye aquí tu código

        //try http GET
        var uri = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);

        request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;

        var client = new HttpClient();
        // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(tok_ty, acc_tok);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);


        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {

            case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):
                HttpContent content = response.Content;
                string xjson = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return "";
    }
```

EL Json que recibo es algo así :

```
    [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  }]
```

Eso es lo que tengo y me manda lo siguiente

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0407  'Task Window2.Button_Click(object, RoutedEventArgs)' has the wrong return type
>    Alguien podría guiarme un poco de como hacer esto bine. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que es un evento y como tal no debería retornar ningún valor, si quieres gestionar un valor de retorno hazlo en una función o método que no cambie la firma del evento original button_click

La firma original viene así:

```
private void BtnRefresh_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //llama a la función ProcessRequest() aquí

}
```

Crea un nuevo método para Gestionar o realizar el procedimiento que requieres:

```
 private async Task<string> ProcessRequest()
 {
     //incluye aquí tu código
 }
```

Tu firma modificada del evento button_click debería quedar así:

```
private async void BtnRefresh_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //llama a la función ProcessRequest()
    var result = await ProcessRequest();

}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: hola actualize mi código como me sugieres pero me sigue saliendo el siguiente error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0407 'Task Window2.Button_Click(object, RoutedEventArgs)' has the wrong return type

Comment: Revisa bien, no tiene que tener Task en el button_click solo el async

Comment: ya la volví a cambiar tengo el mismo error si le quito el async al  Button_Click me manda un monton de errores

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286387/ajax-asp-net-objeto-con-ilistiformfile

Comment: Me parece que no me entendiste, no necesitas adicionar la palabra Task en tu evento click de tu botón. Debe quedar algo así:                        
private async void BtnRefresh_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) luego del private solo tiene la palabra async void sin adicionar nada más