# error al subir archivo con ajax

Tags: php, ajax

tengo un formulario que me inserta en una base de datos, el problema que tengo es que intento subir un archivo a mi server pero no lo sube (si inserta los demás campos que utilizo en la DB ) mi conclusión es que el problema esta en AJAX ya que si en el formulario no utilizo AJAX y utilizo "action" si me sube el archivo, es por eso que no agrego los demás archivos php que utilizo. La verdad he utilizado AJAX muy poco casi nada, tal vez ahí este el problema espero me puedan ayudar.

```
    <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmajax">

            <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom"> </input>

            <br>

            <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo"> </input>

            <select name="area" id="area" class="form-control">


                                                <option selected > Elige un área </option>
                                                <option value="1"> Videojuegos </option>
                                                <option value="2"> Musica </option>
                                                <option value="3"> Peliculas </option>
                                                <option value="4"> Disney </option>
                                                <option value="5"> Marvel </option>
                                                <option value="6"> DC </option>
                                                <option value="7"> Marcas </option>
                                                <option value="8"> Series </option>
                                                <option value="9"> Caricaturas </option>
                                                <option value="10"> Random </option>

                                            </select>



            <button type="submit" id="btnguardar" class="btn btn-success "> AGREGAR </button>

        </form>

         <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnguardar').click(function(){
            var datos=$('#frmajax').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"db.php",
                data:datos,
                success:function(r){
                    if(r==1){
                        alert(" ");

                    }else{

                        alert("Agregado con exito");

                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/286765/822 (ver la parte del AJAX principalmente)

Answer (score 0):

El problema se presenta debido a que la función `serialize` solo envía string o texto, por lo que debes usar la función `formData`, prueba el siguiente Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#frmajax').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var datos = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"db.php",
            data:datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(r){
                if(r==1){
                    alert(" ");
                }else{
                    alert("Agregado con exito");
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Aunque estés en un webhost, elimina el caché y datos del navegador, prueba en una ventana de incógnito y depura la consola, revisa que se esté cargando el código correcto del ajax, con el preventDefault no debería cargar la página.

Comment: no me funciono amigo :(

Comment: ¿Que error le muestra la consola? Lo hiciste desde modo incógnito, recuerda borrar caché y cookies

Comment: estoy probando todo en un webhost y lo que esta pasando es que relleno mis datos en el formulario y simplemente la pagina se refresca y no manda nada a la DB ni me muestra la alerta que tengo en AJAX

Comment: Voy a actualizar la función para prevenir que se envíe el formulario.

Comment: hermano un saludo, me haz resuelto el dia ya funciono muchas gracias

Comment: Un gusto hermano, no olvides marcar la respuesta como respondida.