# Como validar campos que sean obligatorios en el front-end y back-end

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, asp.net-mvc

Estoy creando mi formulario en **ASP.NET MVC** con la ayuda de **C#** y requiero hacer unas validaciones de algunos campos que sean obligatorios tanto en el front como en el back y que no se permitan enviar hasta estar debidamente diligenciados

El siguiente es el formulario con los campos

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
                <div id="informacionTicket" class="user">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                        <div class="card-header py-3">
                            <h4 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Solicitante</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ticketIdAppliInput">Matrícula:</label>
                                    <input maxlength="9" required id="ticketIdAppliInput" type="text" name="matricula" onkeypress="if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) return false;" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ticketNameAppliInput">Nombre completo:</label>
                                    <input maxlength="100" id="ticketNameAppliInput" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ticketEmailAppliInput">Email:</label>
                                    <input maxlength="100" id="ticketEmailAppliInput" type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>       

<button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Enviar</button>
```

El siguiente es la función javascript que envía los datos

```
function f_submitForm() {
        $("#submit").css("display", "none");

        const form = new FormData();

        form.append("ticketIdAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketIdAppliInput").value);
        form.append("ticketNameAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketNameAppliInput").value);
        form.append("ticketEmailAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketEmailAppliInput").value);
$.ajax({
        url: document.getElementById("newTicket").value,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form,
        error: function() {
            alert("Ocurrió un error, porfavor inténtalo de nuevo.");

            $("#submit").css("display", "block");
            $("#load").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
    }
```

**Nota:** No lo hago con la etiqueta required en html porque se puede inspeccionar el elemento y a través del navegador eliminar y es lo que no quiero

**UPDATE:**

Agrego el controlador del formulario

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateNewTicket()
            {
                var ticketIdAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketIdAppliInput"];
                var ticketNameAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketNameAppliInput"];
                var ticketEmailAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketEmailAppliInput"];

            try
            {
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
                {               
                    var ticket = new TK_HD_TICKETS
                    {
                        CUSTOMER_ID = ticketIdAppliInput,
                        CUSTOMER_FULLNAME = ticketNameAppliInput,
                        CUSTOMER_EMAIL = ticketEmailAppliInput,
                        };
                        var result = ticketCreate.CreateNewTicket(ticket);

                        //Si no se guardo el ticket, se termina la transaccion y regresamos el mensaje de error
                        if (!result.Success)
                        return Json(new TicketResult
                        {
                            IsValid = false,
                            Error = "No se pudo crear el ticket, por favor inténtalo de nuevo."
                        });
                }
            }catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                //Falló al tratar de registrar datos en la base de datos
                foreach (var e in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                foreach (var validationError in e.ValidationErrors)
                    Console.WriteLine("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " +
                                      validationError.ErrorMessage);

                return Json(new TicketResult
                {
                    IsValid = false,
                    Error = "Ocurrió un error al crear el ticket, por favor inténtalo de nuevo."
                });
            }
            }
```

Comment: Si necesitas otro tipo de validación te recomiendo que con javascript obtengas el valor de cada campo y realices tu propio validador, y si es que contenga valor y sea del tipo que necesitas, con las mismas propiedades de la etiqueta lo podes controlar

Comment: Puedes darme el ejemplo de como realizar la validacion con javascript y obtener el valor de cada campo

Comment: ¿En qué parte de tu código hay C#? En la versión actual de tu pregunta, es inexistente, ¿olvidaste algo?

Comment: @SebastianSalazar De que tipo es tu aplicación Web, ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @fredyfx revisa nuevamente la pregunta, acabo de agregar el controlador del formulario

Comment: @RafaelAcosta es correcto, utilizo **ASP.NET MVC** y me ayudo con **C#**

Comment: Coloca TODO lo que tienes en `function f_submitForm()`, entre más detalles, más fácil reproducir tu escenario y darte una mejor respuesta.

Comment: @fredyfx Revisa la función javascript se actualizo completa

Comment: Acostúmbrate a realizar preguntas cuyo código esté completo. Por otro lado, A ver si entiendo tu lógica, estás creando una validación que genera un Console.WriteLine del lado del servidor y que para el cliente devuelve un "IsValid = false" y un mensaje de error en la variable "Error", ¿no sería más conveniente mandar un json con el arreglo de errores? De tal manera, en el cliente puedes recorrer dicho arreglo, ver la propiedad que no fue validad y tomar acción.

Comment: @fredyfx Lo del Console.WriteLine del lado del servidor lo realice para pruebas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para validar en **back-end**, lo tienes bastante fácil:

```
        var ticketIdAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketIdAppliInput"].ToString();
        var ticketNameAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketNameAppliInput"].ToString();
        var ticketEmailAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketEmailAppliInput"].ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticketIdAppliInput))
        {
            return Json(new TicketResult
            {
                IsValid = false,
                Error = "No se pudo crear el ticket, por favor inténtalo de nuevo."
            });
        }
```

En cuanto al **front-end**, te aconsejo utilizar ***jquery unobtrusive validate***.
En este artículo: [Validación de formularios en ASP.NET MVC - Unobtrusive Validate](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/11/12/validaci%C3%B3n-de-formularios-en-aspnet-mvc-unobtrusive-validate), podrás encontrar todo lo que necesitas para la validación en cliente (front-end).

Comment: Buen aporte, en caso alguien quiera enviar documentos, esto está relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/286765/822

Comment: No comprendo muy bien el articulo que me dejas sobre validación de formularios, puedes dejarme un ejemplo con el código que tengo para así poderle dar el cierre a la pregunta

Comment: @SebastianSalazar Mírate este artículo entonces: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966378/unobtrusive-client-validation-without-accepting-model

Comment: No me da mucha información y no es clara

Comment: @RafaelAcosta tienes idea de como hacer el mismo de validación en un dropdownlist ?

Comment: @SebastianSalazar: En mi opinión, es mejor que formules una nueva pregunta para la validación en `dropdownlist`, por supuesto con ejemplo de código claro que exponga tu nueva cuestión.