# AJAX ejecuta script's duplicado

Tags: ajax, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un **Evento** que ejecuta una **Action** desde el **controlador** y esta devuelve como resultado final una vista (está incluye el **Layout.cshtml**) y cada vez que ejecuto este evento **AJAX** me duplica los script's y uno de ellos es el **unobtrusive** que me está ocasionando que duplicar todos los métodos que tienen **AjaxBegimForm** (hace una doble ejecución en mis botones).

Como puedo hacer para evitar que al imprimir la página no me duplique los script's cada vez que utilizo el método AJAX.

No se si el problema radica por imprimir la vista así: `$('#divPage').html(response);`

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CargarDoc_Almacen", "Distribucion")',
                method: "POST",
                data: { 'tiDocu': TIPO, 'nuDocu': NRO_DOCUMENTO, 'coAlma': COD_ALMACEN, 'coUnid': COD_UNIDAD },
                success: function (response) {

                    $.getScript("/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxloader.js", function () {
                        $("#jqxLoader").jqxLoader({ isModal: false, text: "", width: 200, height: 70 });
                        $('#jqxLoader').jqxLoader('open');
                    });

                    console.log(response);
                    $('#divPage').html(response);

                },

                error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                },

                async: true
            });
```

El siguiente código pertenece a mí layout (que contiene dichos script's y veo que duplica, el layout es impreso al estar enlazado con mi vista).

```
@{
    string Version = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["versionERP"];
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title GSMARK</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <link href="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/js/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    @*<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>*@

</head>
<body>

    <div id="jqxLoader">
    </div>

    <div id="divPage" class="portada" style="width:100%; height:100%">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#jqxMenu").jqxMenu({ width: '280', mode: 'vertical' });
                $("#jqxMenu").css('visibility', 'visible');
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Loading() {
                $.getScript("/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxloader.js", function () {
                    $("#jqxLoader").jqxLoader({ isModal: false, text: "Cargando, por favor espere...", width: 200, height: 70 });
                    console.log('_LayoutLoader');
                    $('#jqxLoader').jqxLoader('open');
                });
            }

            Loading();
        </script>

        <div id='jqxWidget' style='width: 21.5%; height:700px' class="col-md-5">
            <div id='jqxMenu' style="visibility: hidden;">
                <ul>
                    <li style="height:50px"><b><a href="~/Principal/Index"> <img src="~/Imagenes/Shared/tio-rico7.3.png" width="45" height="45" /> SISTEMA TIO RICO </a></b></li>

                    <div class="contenedor-datos-login" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                        <div class="columna-icono"><i class="far fa-user" style="font-size:45px"></i></div>
                        <div class="columna-derecha"><b>Bienvenido: </b> @ViewBag.Message01</div>
                        <div class="columna-derecha"><b>Tipo de Usuario: </b> @ViewBag.Message02</div>
                    </div>

                    <li><a href="~/Principal/Index"><i class="icono izquierda fas fa-home"></i><b> MENÚ PRINCIPAL </b></a></li>

                    <li>
                        <i class="icono izquierda fas fa-warehouse"></i> Almacén</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Requerimiento de Almacén", "Requerimiento", "Requerimiento")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Ingreso de Productos ", "Abastecimiento", "Abastecimiento")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Salida de Productos ", "Distribucion", "Distribucion")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Solicitud de Pedido", "Pedido", "Requerimiento")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fas fa-shopping-bag"></i> Compras </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Registro Orden de Compra", "OrdCompras", "OrdCompra")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fas fa-swatchbook"></i> Planta</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Pedido Insumos", "ReqPlanta", "Requerimiento")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Salida de Insumos", "Distribucion", "Distribucion")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Control de Producción", "Produccion", "Produccion")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Ventas </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Seleccionar Sede y Unidad Negocio", "Elegir_Datos", "Ventas")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Registro de Ventas", "Ventas", "Ventas")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cierre de Liquidación", "CierreLiquidacion", "Ventas")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Inventario de Productos", "Inventario", "Ventas")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fas fa-poll"></i> Reportes </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Reporte de Ventas</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Reporte Liquidación de Venta</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Reporte de Almacén</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Reporte Planta de Producción</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fas fa-user-cog"></i> Mantenimiento </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Perfiles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Configuración de Receta", "Receta", "Receta")</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Merma</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Asignación</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Unidad de medida</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icono izquierda fas fa-info"></i> Información - Ayuda </a></li>
                    @Html.Partial("_estadoLogin")
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="width:85%; height:100%; margin-left:21%">
            @*<img class="img-responsive" src="~/Imagenes/Home/fondoPrincipalTioRico.png" style="width:100%; height:100%" />*@
        </div>

        @RenderBody()

        <div class="contenedor-inferior" style="margin-top:20px">
            <b>Copyright © Todos los Derechos Reservados @DateTime.Now.Year - Versión v.@Version</b>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unobtrusive")*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqwidgets")


    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Estoy detectando la duplicidad de script's desde la consola del navegador (lo que están marcados son los que sé duplican luego de ejecutar el evento en AJAX.)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>  en la declaracion estas cargando dos archivos dif version elimina la segunda

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/286765/822